# Team Foundation server

Tags: tfs

In team foundation server 2010, is it possible to version control for user stories(For change request if we change the user story, we want to keep another version)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In TFS, User Stories are stored as Work Items. For each Work Item, a history of each revision is stored that includes all of the fields that were changed along with their old and new values. You can review the history of a Work Item in the Work Item Editor. Using the API, you can retrieve any previous version of a Work Item.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  User Stories are stored in a work item.  All work items are, by their nature, version controlled.  Each work item has a full history available.